# C# Scripting inside Java

Tags: c#, java, scripting

I know that I can use Lua Script files to manipulate Java Objects by using libraries like [LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/). I had this idea of using C# scripts instead~

Is it possible to run C# scripts inside Java?

Comment: C# isn't really a "scripting" language.

Comment: For that matter, strictly speaking neither is Java.  Javascript is, Java is not, and there is no "C#script" counterpart.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior [Of course it is!](http://www.doolwind.com/blog/why-you-should-use-csharp-for-your-scripting-language/)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Doesn't really matter.  I've read of cases when studying game design of engines injecting the JVM and using Java as a scripting language (note that I said Java, not Javascript!)

Comment: @TEG, try telling those crazy folks at BeanShell that Java isnt a scripting language ;). +1 to OP, great question and if you find something please let us know. Imagine LINQ yumminess in the JVM. Gimme!

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: If you're implying what I fear you are, consider the saying "Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet." and give yourself a quick primer on the principles on both languages.

Comment: What I'm saying is that Java is a full blown OO language which, like C# is compiled to MSIL, is itself compiled to ByteCode, which is then compiled into machine code on the target platform, while Javascript is a non object oriented scripting language that DERIVES from the Java language but is interpreted on the fly most commonly in a browser context.  AFAICT, Beanshell is an *interpreter* that allows you to execute dyanmic Java, to be sure, and you can do similar things with C# as well, but INTRINSICALLY, Java is not Javascript and C# has no "scripting" counterpart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, yes - you can certainly do this in .Net applications and there are Java / .Net interops.

Typically however Java / C# interops are performed through either P/Invoke or COM - both are pretty cumbersome for this sort of thing and so in reality this probably won't work as neatly as you might have imagined.

All the same if you did want to do this I'd probably recommend that you write the "scripting engine" (i.e. wrapper around the C# compiler) in C#, and then have that expose it to Java land via interops, for example:

```
public ScriptResult(string Script)
{
    // Implemented in .Net
    // Script is a string containing the C# code to execute
}
```

You then need to think carefully about how your C# scripts are going to be able to access any Java-land functionality, again I imagine the best way would be to implement a .Net wrapper class that calls Java objects through interops.

Using C# as a scripting language from within a .Net application is surprisingly straightforward - for information see:

- [Why You Should Use C# For Your Scripting Language](http://www.doolwind.com/blog/why-you-should-use-csharp-for-your-scripting-language/)
- [C# As a Scripting Language in your .NET Applications](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/09/c-as-scripting-language-in-your-net.html)

Answer (score 2):

Are C# programs "scripts"? Regardless, you could run most all outside programs from via Runtime.exec(...), but be sure to watch for traps: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Things get a bit more tricky if you wish to have two-way communication between C# and Java, which can be done via simple sockets/streams or all the way up to COM interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way around. Have a look at http://www.ikvm.net/ - it allows object/library reuse from one language in the other.